# Display bluetooth name instead of MAC address in ListView when passing adapter with ArrayList of type BluetoothDevice as last argument

Tags: android, android-listview, bluetooth

The following code shows the MAC address of each bluetooth found on the listview since I am passing ArrayList of type BluetoothDevice.  I know I can get the name of each bluetooth device by using BlueToothDevice.EXTRA_NAME and then put all of them in an ArrayList of type String then pass this ArrayList to get what I want.  However, I can't do that because ArrayList of type BluetoothDevice are those devices (with the MAC address) that I need to connect to when user clicks on it.  This way I can connect to each of the bluetooth device but on the listview only the MAC address of each bluetooth device is shown.  How can I make it to show the bluetooth's name instead of its MAC address and still able to connect. Thank You.

```
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);

btListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I just found a solution to get the name display and able to connect when I click on each of the item by keeping two sets of ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> and ArrayList<String>.  
ArrayList<String> is to be passed into the adapter.  In response of the onItemClick event of each item, I search the bluetooth name of my clicked device against the ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> to get the MAC address for connection.  

So extra step is used to make it work.  And a potential problem if two or more bluetooth devices with the same name, only the first one will be connected.

Comment: post it as an answer. Don't leave your question unanswered